# How to retrieve only one field from a table with many fields using Linq query and EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a table with various fields and I would like to know how to retrieve only one of those fields using linq and put them to list?

```
var st = context.myTable.FirstOrDefault.ToList
```

Comment: `var st = context.myTable.Select(x => x.SomeProperty);`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
var st = context.myTable.Select(x => x.SomeProperty).ToList();
```